# Exchange server cannot connect to remote host

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange, exchange-2013

I have installed a Microsoft Exchange 2013 server on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 machine. I've installed both Mailbox and Client Access roles. All the prerequisites have been installed. [I found a fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2027064) for this problem, but it tells me to run the following query on the Exchange Management Shell:

```
(Get-User username).RemotePowershellEnabled
Set-User username -RemotePowerShellEnabled $True
```

However, I cannot do that since I can't even connect to the server.

**Can anyone provide any help?**

The error I get when I open the Exchange Management shell is the following:

[image: The error I get when I open the Exchange Management shell]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to change anything within Exchange - it should work straight out of the box. The error you have posted is usually due an issue with IIS, as EMS connects to Exchange through the web site.
Therefore check whether the IIS services are running. 
Did you install all of the pre-requisites for Exchange 2013? Did you install Exchange 2013 from the latest cumulative update? Is the machine a domain controller as well? All of those can cause this problem.

Simon.

Comment: If IIS wasn't running, most exchange services would be failing.  It'd be like examining a blister while your hair was on fire.  This is going to be lower level OS connectivity related.  If WS-Management ports cannot communicate to each other (due to firewall) this is exactly what they'd see.